# Are there any tools to monitor IIS requests on a 64 bit server?

Tags: debugging, iis-6

Are there any tools available to monitor all current IIS requests on a server? I have some requests that are hanging, and I'd like to be able to identify which requests are hung, and then kill those specific requests, without affecting the rest of the requests, or the server itself.

I know that the IIS toolkit has a tool called "Requests Viewer" that does most of what I need, but it doesn't work on a 64 bit server.

Does anyone know of a tool that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the [x64 Trace Diagnostics](http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1312) tools? I haven't run IIS Request Viewer before, but it certainly appears that it would work on x64....

Edit: [Trace Diagnostics](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=30D8DAAF-2961-4578-B563-DCB9EEB70C53&displaylang=en) specifically calls out "Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2 x64 Edition" as a supported OS. Perhaps you have some other issue? Are you sure you're on x64 (yeah - I know, it's an odd question, but sometimes you have to ask...it could be ia-64 (Itanium))

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I can't get that installed. When I try it says that "This package is not supported by this processor type". I have the 64bit version, and trying to install it on a Server x64 Standard, SP2 server. The system requirements do specifically say SP1, so I wonder if that may be it.

Comment: I'm running a standard Intel Xeon 5160, something I would think it could be installed on.

Comment: Oddly enough I was able to get it installed using the full IIS Diagnostics x64 installer. Even though it still installed the x86 version, I was able to see requests. However, I still don't have an option of killing requests once I have a stalled one.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to install a proxy before IIS that logs the requests.